# Spray Client (i.e. AKKA) within Tomcat, cause Threading issue

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, akka, spray

I am using spray client i.e. akka within a Tomcat webApp.

While I do properly destroy the actor system on tomcat shutdown via spring, i'm nevertheless still facing this threading issue.

I found that this issue was already reported few years ago [Tomcat complaints when re-deploying servlet with akka inside](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2672#/activity/ticket:), but could not find the solution for it

I'm using the default spray-client configuration.

here is the error that i get when i stop tomcat. (Sorry for the amount of information but i try to give as much clue as possible)

> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.516 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [PoolPartyConnector-ActorSystem-scheduler-1] but has failed to stop
>   it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>
> Stack trace of
>   thread:  java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) 
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.waitNanos(Scheduler.scala:226) 
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:405)
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:375)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.516 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [PoolPartyConnector-ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] but
>   has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Stack trace of thread:  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075) 
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.516 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [PoolPartyConnector-ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] but
>   has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Stack trace of thread: 
>   akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch$class.watchingContains(DeathWatch.scala:73)
>   akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch$class.watchedActorTerminated(DeathWatch.scala:54)
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.watchedActorTerminated(ActorCell.scala:369) 
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:455) 
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478) 
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263) 
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:241) 
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) 
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) 
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.517 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [PoolPartyConnector-ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] but
>   has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Stack trace of thread:  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075) 
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Another part of the trace says:

> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.571 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [oai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@14483049]) and a
>   value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter]
>   (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@752622d4])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak.

10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.571 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [oai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value
>   [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@20399e41]) and a value
>   of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value
>   [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@1286565]) but failed to
>   remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to
>   be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
>
> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.571 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [oai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [scala.util.DynamicVariable$$anon$1] (value
>   [scala.util.DynamicVariable$$anon$1@64b67887]) and a value of type
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler] (value
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler@523e426f]) but failed to
>   remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to
>   be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
>
> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.571 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [oai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@14483049]) and a
>   value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter]
>   (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@20c2d647])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak.

Finally toward the end i get the following

> 10-Jun-2015 12:54:22.574 INFO [PoolPartyConnector-ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [scala.util.control.NonFatal$]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [scala.util.control.NonFatal$]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1196)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anon$2.uncaughtException(ActorSystem.scala:511)
>       at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:405)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

PS:

This is causing an issue in my Intellij. Indeed, i can still start and stop from the terminal tomcat. However, from within Intellij I get the following on restart:

**Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use**

I have to kill the process on 1099 every time to restart from within intellij.